# Strange behavior with basic I/O

Tags: c

There is something strange going on in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counts=0,x;
    while ((x=getchar()) != EOF)
        counts += 1;
    printf("%d",counts);

    return 0;
}
```

When I input `asd^Z\n` (`^Z` represents an `EOF`, `\n` represents Enter), the output is `4` instead of `3`;
When I input `asd\n`, `^Z\n`, the output becomes `3`.
So, what makes it different? Why in the first try the program takes the `EOF` into account?

Comment: If you are programming in C, don't tag the question with C++.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I don't see any uninitialized variable use here.

Comment: @user3477950 Some people consider code like `{ int x; ... ; x = foo();` to be bad, since `x` for a while is uninitalized, until the call to `foo()`. I disgree, but perhaps this is what Daniel Daranas meant.

Comment: @unwind Hm, OK, I see. (I disagree with that reasoning too, since compilers supply excellent warnings nowadays.)

Comment: @DanielDaranas All of which are entirely irrelevant to the question at hand, and also rather subjective. Also `while ((x=getchar()) != EOF)` is a commonly enough used idiom in C to not warrant any criticism.

Comment: @user3477950 I'm sorry for that....  Just thought C is the subset of C++.... QAQ

Comment: @Vince_Wang No, C is not a subset of C++. It never was.

Comment: @user3477950 I'll try to figure it out, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows:
If you hit asd^Z\n , the CTRL-Z does not end the input, so it's not an EOF condition, it's simply the ascii code 26 (the "subsitute" character.)

In a windows console, a line needs to start with CTRL-Z to result in an EOF condition.

(Keep in mind that EOF is not a character, it's a just condition that means there's no more input available. The operating system takes care of transforming the CTRL+Z keystroke to do whatever it needs to end the standard input of your program - but it does that only if CTRL-Z is at the beginning of a line)